# React app different on localhost and on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been working on my web portfolio lately and have recently deployed it to my website.
For some reason, the css is different on the website than on my localhost preview. Some text is much smaller, the colors aren't as vibrant, and the spacing is off.
as an example on my localhost: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/freecodecamp/optimized/3X/4/c/4c6cfdde390e68c4f531ed2df4f02513e86e1563_2_1035x550.png
and on the website it looks like this: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/freecodecamp/optimized/3X/1/1/11c89209bd4400171f02e90286edde009b24ae54_2_1035x607.png
Any idea what is causing this?
In case it is relevant, here is my source code https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/Dylanbozarth.com
thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer after looking through the css files. In my css file I had several different places changing `<h1>`. So I changed each of these tags to `<p>` and set their size with a specific class.
I'm not sure why it was showing it as different on my localhost, but I hope that helps whoever runs accross this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the same browser to view both times?  Is it possible that the code is not exactly the same on deployment? Maybe an extra css file is being used?

Comment: It is the same browser. and I am putting everything that is in the static Css folder in the folder on cpanel. Should I not put it all in there?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this one may be your in another folder then the URL of the style.css became wrong so kindly put the CSS in your code to something like this:

import '../App.css'

if it's still not yet working, sometimes you have to use the hard refresh on your keyboard:

type this. `ctrl + F5` or `ctrl + shift + r`. I am sharing this because this happened to me and I want to help people when I know the answer. Let me know if I helped. Good Luck and Take Care

It's also almost the same here [Bootstrap style disappearing on refresh only on one page in React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211003/bootstrap-style-disappearing-on-refresh-only-on-one-page-in-react-app/63212140#63212140). Hope you got the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Where should I modify the import app.css? if I add the extra dot in my app.js file it breaks everything.

Comment: did you try ctrl + shift + r on your keyboard